# Сериализация объекта с Date

Tags: json, actionscript-3

Добрый день!

Сразу скажу, что вопрос именно по Action Script. В том же C# всё делается на ура без бубна.

Имеется клиент на Flash (ActionScript, никаких Flex) и ASP.NET-сервер. Между ними гоняются данные в JSON. Моделька объекта простейшая, но именно в ней - затык:

```
class Simple
{

public var Name:String;
public var Number: String;
public var RegistrationDate: Date;


public var data: Array = new Array();
}
```

У меня никак не получается так сериализовать Simple, чтобы это было понятно серверу. Серверу нужна Date сериализованая во что-то вроде *Date(1433414354166)* (Unix формат вроде), а класс JSON в ActionScript сериализует дату в *2015-04-06T13:43:18.605Z*.

Сервер принимает данные в *Date(1433414354166)* потому, что там используется json-десериализатор (JavaScriptSerializer). Сервер переписать не предлагать.

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы класс Date из ActionScript 3 нормально преобразовался в unix-формат, да ещё и был в JSONе? Я естественно сделал как советуют мануалы:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function (k):*
{
 return "/Date(" + this.getTime() + ")/";
}
```

Но сервер это тоже не принимает. Второй день уже бьюсь... помогите!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал следующим образом, например:

```
var someClass:Simple = new Simple;
someClass.Name = "someName";
someClass.Number = "12345";
someClass.RegistrationDate = new Date();
var array:Array = [someClass.Name, someClass.Number, "/Date(" + someClass.RegistrationDate.getTime() + ")/"];//тут можно использовать ассоциативный массив с ключами вида "Name" или "Number". В зависимости от того, что вас сервер принимает.
var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify(array); //JSON библиотека верхнего уровня, подключать ее не нужно
```